# Nodejs - Variable initialized inside a function is undefined outside it

Tags: node.js, json, csv, module, export

I have a nodejs module which is supposed to convert a csv file to json, however the variable which is supposed to hold the json array is undefined outside the function, even though it's declared outside.

```js
const csvFilePath='data.csv'
const csv=require('csvtojson')
let userDB;

const loadUserDB = async() => {
  userDB = await csv().fromFile(csvFilePath);
  console.log(userDB[0]);
  return userDB; 
};

console.log(userDB[0]);

module.exports = {
  loadUserDB,
  userDB
}
```

I'm new to nodejs so I couldn't figure it out, any ideas?

Comment: When referencing your variables, reference them as e.g.: this.userDB

Comment: @Elijah I have tried this, didn't work

Comment: where is your method require()?

Comment: @Elijah I'm calling loadUserDB in index.js, it gets there undefined.
I added the console.log(userDB[0]) to check and I discovered that it faild because userDB is undefined, so it looks like I'm exporting the variable as undefined.

Comment: For testing purpose, set define the userDB. let userDB: any[] = [];

Answer (score 1):

You should probably wait for the asynchronous function to run before you access the variable (or remove the `async`). Edit: And you never call `loadUserDB`, at least not in this code. I suggest that, instead of using a wider scoped variable, you simply `await` the result of your function.

Comment: I call loadUserDB in index.js

Answer (score 0):

```js
const csvFilePath='data.csv'
const csv=require('csvtojson')
let userDB;

const loadUserDB = async() => {
  userDB = await csv().fromFile(csvFilePath);
  console.log(userDB[0]);
  return userDB; 
};

// here this always be undefined - why?
// when the index.js file import this module, this file going to run line by line,
// means first the program just registers the userDB and the loadUserDB variables
// without of course executing the function
// so basically this files run in this form only once
// this console.log never going to run after the loadUserDB
console.log(userDB[0]);

module.exports = {
  loadUserDB,
  userDB
}
```

My advise to check out how scopes and closures work in JavaScript.

Again, you will have undefined the `userDB` in the moment of the import, and before executing `loadUserDB`. This module (file) only runs once in this form.

After calling `loadUserDB`, `userDB` suppose to have some other value than undefined.

So yes, this value is not always undefined, just the matter of time when you want to access it.

```js
const path = require('path');
const csvFilePath = path.join(__dirname, './data.csv')
const csv = require('csvtojson')
let userDB;

const loadUserDB = async() => {
  userDB = await csv().fromFile(csvFilePath);
};

module.exports = {
  loadUserDB,
  userDB
}
```

Comment: Actually userDB seems to always be undefined, even if I try to access it from index.js

Comment: what is in your index.js?